# Windows 7 Deleted User Account Reappearing

Tags: windows-7, security, user-accounts

After using **Password Renew for NT's v1.1-BETA by sala** (it comes with Hirens boot cd) and creating a new administrator user I'm unable to delete it. Actualy I delete it but it reappears after reboot. I see other people have the same problem [here](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/36468-deleted-user-account-reappearing.html).
Are there other methods of removing users? Maybe editing the SAM file?

[image: Password Renew for NT's v1.1-BETA by sala]

Comment: How did you delete it? Also, don't edit the SAM file.

Comment: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-create-hidden-user-account-hide-user-account-from-welcome-screen-in-windows/ maybe this link may helpful for hiding your account from welcomescreen

Answer (score 0):

Launch regedit, and locate

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Passwdrenew"

Delete the whole entry, as well as the file mentioned "rnpassword.exe" in system32 folder.

---

This is what the author said in the comment section of the software:

> Windows Password Renew installs password reseting service which executes net.exe and makes requested changes (changes a password, converts user to admin or makes new user). After this is done cleanup.bat will be made and executed which removes password reseting service and itself.

I suggest that the service is not correctly deleted.

Hunt down the service and you should be good to go :)